# Question about a function implementation in Ethereum Account Abstraction

Tags: solidity, opcode

```
function numberMarker() internal view {
    assembly {mstore(0, number())}
}
```

I'm studying about Account Abstraction, and exploring through the implementation code of EntryPoint.sol by Infinitism. Link is [here](https://github.com/eth-infinitism/account-abstraction).

However, I'm stuck in the function numberMarker()...

It seems to store NUMBER opcode in the 0x00 part of memory, but they are saying that it can be used as marker for banned opcode.

Is it used as a marker for bundlers to verify if banned opcodes are used? How does this code work?

I've seen the full code of [EntryPoint.sol](https://github.com/eth-infinitism/account-abstraction/blob/develop/contracts/core/EntryPoint.sol), but can't find any clues for its usage. It is only called inside some functions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the eip-4337: https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-4337#simulation

The client(or bundler) simulated call performs the full validation before submitting on-chain, by calling:

1. If initCode is present, `factory.createSender()`
2. `account.validateUserOp()`
3. If paymaster is present, `paymaster.validatePaymasterUserOp()`

These calls differ in their banned OpCodes and policies.

For example:

The `CREATE2` opcode is banned for `validateUserOp()` and `validatePaymasterUserOp()` but allows to call for `factory.createSender()`.

To enable a client to distinguish opcodes between them, within contracts, there is a call to the NUMBER opcode (block.number), used as a delimiter between the 3 functions. While simulating userOp validation.

You can see the `numberMarker` calling within

**EntryPoint:** https://github.com/eth-infinitism/account-abstraction/blob/465f22310fcc639964e6ab5f8aa648770c6d8981/contracts/core/EntryPoint.sol

From `EntryPoint`, the `numberMarker` will be called 2 times sequentially to separate the 3 opcodes sections.

---

> **Most important**, currently, the bundler uses top-level calls instead of this
> approach to scan banned OpCodes:
> https://github.com/eth-infinitism/bundler/pull/116
>
> Can find the example of how the bundler scans banned OpCodes from:
> https://github.com/eth-infinitism/bundler/blob/65f56cfc9c739b594279469de924730517209244/packages/bundler/src/parseScannerResult.ts#L172

Comment: Thanks, it helped a lot :)